# Select 1st result from result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, row-number

this is my sql server query result, I just need only one data from one minute, now 5th minute contain multiple data, as like 10th minute too

my sql server query

```
select top 1000 val1,val2,timestamp
from VTagValue
where datepart(mi,timestamp)%5=0 `

83.2    83.4    2015-08-29 13:05:53.0730000 +08:00
83.2    83.4    2015-08-29 13:05:55.0730000 +08:00
83.2    83.4    2015-08-29 13:05:57.0730000 +08:00
84.0    84.2    2015-08-29 13:10:01.0730000 +08:00
84.0    84.2    2015-08-29 13:10:03.0730000 +08:00
84.0    84.2    2015-08-29 13:10:05.0730000 +08:00
```

expected result

```
83.2    83.4    2015-08-29 13:05:53.0730000 +08:00
84.0    84.2    2015-08-29 13:10:01.0730000 +08:00
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select val1, val2, timestamp 
from
(
select val1,val2, timestamp,
row_number() over(partition by datepart(mi,timestamp) order by timestamp) as rn 
from VTagValue 
where datepart(mi,timestamp)%5=0 
) t 
where rn = 1;
```

You can use `row_number` to get the earliest timestamp for a minute.

Edit: As per OP's comments:

```
select val1, val2, timestamp 
from
(
select val1,val2, timestamp,
row_number() over(partition by datepart(hh,timestamp),datepart(mi,timestamp) 
                  order by timestamp) as rn 
from VTagValue 
where datepart(mi,timestamp)%5=0 
) t 
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: this code is working, but logic has been missed in one scenario., system retrieves only 1st hour result, let's say if our interval is 8am to 10am then it retrieves only 8am to 9am result??, is there any solution for this?

Comment: You should also partition on `hour` part of datetime then. See if the modified version is what you are looking for.